# mongoclient remove collection nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to remove the entire collection, but it is not working with the below nodejs code. The same works within mongodb using command [db.collection.remove()]

1. There are no errors, but the below returns count of events as 0

   ```
   smevents.count(function(err, count) {
       console.log("There are " + count + " records.");
   });
   ```
2. The removed entries shows as 0 from below-

   ```
   console.log("Removed collection entries " + collectionName + "," + removed);
   ```
3. The collectionName used is as per the one obtained from -

   ```
   db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
       console.log(collections);
   });
   ```

Below is the code-

```
function removeMongoDBCollection(db, collectionName, callback) {

    console.log('collectionname ' + collectionName);

    db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
        console.log(collections);
    });

    db.collection(collectionName, {}, function(err, smevents) {

        console.log('Error Getting collection ' + err);

        smevents.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log("There are " + count + " records.");
        });

        smevents.remove({}, function(err, removed) {

            console.log('Error Removing collection ' + err);
            console.log("Removed collection entries " + collectionName + "," + removed);

            db.close(); 
            callback(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking.  Can you edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do and what isn't working?  Are you trying to remove the collection itself or just the docs within it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the concept of callbacks here as all the methods are asynchronous and you need to wait for them to complete before moving on. For example your "count" method is not necessarily occuring before "remove", as you have not waited for that to complete.

The [**async**](https://github.com/caolan/async) module can help you here in avoiding "indentation creep" when nesting methods in callbacks. Here is a general reworking of the logic with [**async.waterfall**](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) to help in passing though variables obtained.

Note that both in your function implementation and the demonstration flow you are "moving on" to the next "task" when the operation is complete by firing inside the callback:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongo = require('mongodb');
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;


// Function implementation
function removeCollection(db,collectionName,callback) {

  async.waterfall([

    // Get collection
    function(cb) {
      db.collection(collectionName,function(err,collection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cb(null,collection);
      });
    },

    // Count collection current
    function(collection,cb) {
      collection.count(function(err,count) {
        console.log(
          "%s collection has %s documents",
          collectionName,
          count
        );
        cb(null,collection);
      });
    },

    // Remove collection documents
    function(collection,cb) {
      collection.remove({},function(err,removed) {
        console.log(
          "%s collection removed %s documents",
          collectionName,
          removed
        );
        cb(null,collection);
      });
    },

  ],function(err,collection) {

    collection.count(function(err,count) {
      console.log(
        "%s collection now has %s documents",
        collectionName,
        count
      );
      callback(err);
    });

  });
}

// Main flow after connection
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  if (err) throw err;

  async.waterfall([

    // Set up a collection
    function(cb) {
      var collectionName = "sample";

      db.collection(collectionName,function(err,collection) {
        cb(null,collection,collectionName);
      });
    },

    // Insert some things
    function(collection,collectionName,cb) {
      async.eachSeries([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],function(item,complete) {
        collection.insert({ "item": item },function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          complete();
        });
      },function(err) {
        // When all are complete
        cb(null,collectionName);
      });
    },

    // Call your remove method
    function(collectionName,cb) {

      removeCollection(db,collectionName,function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        cb();
      });

    }

  ]);

});
```